# Rack seems to think my environment is ' ' when it is production

Tags: capistrano3, puma

Rack app error: #  in puma log
when running capistrano production deploy.

Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.1.0'
gem 'mysql'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

gem 'spring',        group: :development
gem 'puma'

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano3-puma'
  gem 'rvm1-capistrano3',require: false
end
gem 'capistrano3-nginx'
```

deploy.rb:

```
lock '3.2.1'

set :application, 'foobar'
set :repo_url, '/home/joeradtke/rails/foobar/.git'
set :app_port, '8500'
set :nginx_domains, "radtke.in www.radtke.in"
set :nginx_template, "config/nginx.conf.erb"

set :app_server_socket, "#{shared_path}/sockets/puma-#{fetch :application}.sock"

set :deploy_to, '/home/joe/foobar'
set :deploy_user, 'joe'
set :sudo_user, 'joe'

set :stage, :production

set :puma_init_active_record, true
set :puma_env, :production
set :puma_state, "#{shared_path}/tmp/pids/puma.state"

set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}
set :rvm1_ruby_version, "2.1.2"

set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

set :ssh_options, {
  config:false
}
namespace :deploy do
  after :deploy, "nginx:restart"
  after :deploy, "puma:restart" 
end
```

deploy/production.rb:

```
server 'radtke.in', user: 'joe', roles: %w{web app}, primary: true

  set :ssh_options, {
    keys: %w(/home/joe/.ssh/id_rsa),
    forward_agent: true,
    auth_methods: %w(publickey)
  }
```

Capfile:

```
require 'capistrano/setup'

require 'capistrano/deploy'

require 'rvm1/capistrano3'

require 'capistrano/rails'
require 'capistrano/puma'
require 'capistrano/puma/jungle'
require 'capistrano/puma/monit'

require 'capistrano/nginx'

Dir.glob('lib/capistrano/tasks/*.rake').each { |r| import r }
```

cap production deploy runs fine but
web page at root shows:

"A really lowlevel plumbing error occured. Please contact your local Maytag(tm) repair man."

can server assets so nginx is fine.

I think I've put production everywhere.

Even tried adding 
'': 
secret_key_base:.................. to secret.yml file.

I've been fooling with this for two days.  Usually can find online answer but not for this.  Please help.

Joe Radtke

Answer (score 1):

I ran in to this same problem today while migrating an app from an old Rails 1.9.3 Suspenders environment to a new Rails 2.0 environment on AWS.

First the message the error message "A really lowlevel plumbing error occured. Please contact your local Maytag(tm) repair man." is some smartass way of saying that there was an error with Puma and you should look in puma.log to see what the error is...

```
tail -f /var/log/puma/puma.log
```

In my case I found this line:

```
Rack app error: #<RuntimeError: Missing `secret_key_base` for 'production' environment, set this value in `config/secrets.yml`>
```

sadly I'm not nerd enough to tell you exactly why this was an issue, but I can tell you that my config/secrets.yml was not the issue.  For some reason that file wasn't getting loaded correctly in production, so I did two things.  First I made sure that the puma gem was getting loaded in production:

```
group :production do
  gem 'puma'
end
```

I still had problems so I had a look at the application.rb file and changed

```
# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
require "http_logger"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env)
```

to

```
require 'rails/all'

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)
```

Which is what we were using in our newer rails environment.